# How to overwrite file in FileSystem API

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, html5-filesystem, persistent-storage

Here is the function:

```
this.saveObj = function(o, finished)
{   
    root.getDirectory("object", {create: true}, function(directoryEntry)
    {
        directoryEntry.getFile("object.json", {create: true}, function(fileEntry) 
        {
            fileEntry.createWriter(function(fileWriter) 
            {

                fileWriter.onwriteend = function(e) 
                {
                    finished(fileEntry);
                };

                fileWriter.onerror = errorHandler;
                var blob = new Blob([JSON.stringify(o)], {type: "json"});

                fileWriter.write(blob);
            }, errorHandler);
        }, errorHandler);
    }, errorHandler);
};
```

Now when I save an object everything works fine. Lets say I save `{"id":1}` my file content would be `{"id":1}`. Now I edit the object with `o = {};` and save it again, my file content suddenly is `{} "id":1 }`.

It just overwrites the old content, but doesn't clean it. Do I have to delete the file before writing it or is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For as far as I understand the write method will write the supplied content to a position. To me this implies that the existing content is untouched unless you are overwriting parts. So I'm going to say yes, delete the file and save a new one.

[source](http://dev.w3.org/2009/dap/file-system/file-writer.html#methods-2)

Answer (score 0):

According to the Mozilla documentation using only `{ create: true}` :

> The existing file or directory is removed and replaced with a new one,
>   then the successCallback is called with a FileSystemFileEntry or a
>   FileSystemDirectoryEntry, as appropriate.

<s>Tested in Chrome 72 this seems to be the case.</s>

This does not work as the file seems to be persist. The file will be overwritten (first bytes) but the size will remain the same. So this is a bug in at least Chrome 72.

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileSystemFlags/create)